# Remove version suffixes from filename

Tags: regex, sed

I want to create shell command to extract short name from shared library name removing extension, `lib` prefix and standard versioning suffixes. Such command must work on any library names:

```
libexample.so -> example
example2.so -> example2
libexample-win32.so -> example-win32
libexample-15.so -> example
libexample-2.0.so -> example
libexample-2.0-15.so -> example
libexample-64-2.0-15.so -> example-64
libexample-16-to-10-converter-2.0-4.so -> example-16-to-10-converter
libexample-library2-64bit-2.0-15.so -> example-library2-64bit
```

Currently I have this command:

```
basename libexample-library2-64bit-2.0-15.so .so | sed -nre 's;(lib)*(.*)((-[.0-9]+)|$);\2;p'
```

It gives me

```
example-library2-64bit-2.0
```

But I can't move forward and make `sed` to remove suffix `-2.0`. I have tried:

```
basename libexample-library2-64bit-2.0-15.so .so | sed -nre 's;(lib)*(.*)((-[.0-9]+-[.0-9]+)|(-[.0-9]+)|$);\2;p'
```

but it gives me `example-library2-64bit-2.0`. As I understand, it is because of greedy nature of `sed` regexp parsing.

Is there any way to modify my regexp to remove both version suffixes?

Comment: @Sundeep Unfortunately not because library name may contain dash and digits within its name. For example: `libexample-16-to-10-converter.so`

Comment: how about `sed -E 's/^lib|\.so$//g; s/(-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)?(-[0-9]+)?$//'` does it work for all your cases? (no need basename)

Comment: @Sundeep My answer was on your first comment. Your second suggestion fails on `libexample-64-2.0-15.so` :( I need to remove only last 2 numbers not all of them. I've updated my question with examples

Comment: @Sundeep Third option works fine. Make it an answer I'll accept it

Comment: if under any [tag:shell], you could use *Parameter Expansion* instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -E 's/^lib|(-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)?(-[0-9]+)?\.so$//g'
```

- `^lib` remove `lib` from start of line
- `(-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)?` this will optionally match `-` followed by digits followed by optional `.` and digits

  - if you always have the second part, you can simplify it to `(-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)?`
- `(-[0-9]+)?` optionally match `-` followed by digits
- `\.so` match the extension

The `?` quantifier matches `0` or `1` times of the preceding element. Since it is greedy, it will match whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
sed -E 's/^lib|[0-9]\.{1,}.*\.so|-[0-9]+\.so//g;s/-$|\.so$//g' Input_file
```

Comment: 2nd and 3rd line doesn't match expected output

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov, Could you please check it now and lemme know if this helps you?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `sed` with 2 alternations in regex:

```
sed -E 's/^lib|(-[0-9]+(\.[0-9.-]+)*)?\.[a-z]+$//g' file
```

```
example
example2
example-win32
example
example
example
example-64
example-16-to-10-converter
example-library2-64bit
```

Regex is using 2 alternations:

- `^lib`: Match `lib` at start
- `|`: OR
- `(-[0-9]+(\.[0-9.-]+)*)?\.[a-z]+$`: Match `-` followed by 1+ digits in an optional group that must have a dot followed by file extension before end

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Exco6V/4)

Comment: based on given sample and your solution, I think `sed -E 's/^lib|(-[0-9]+)?\..*//g'` will work too

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep, yes indeed that will be shorter than this

Comment: This command fails on `libexample-64.4-abc64-5.0-20.so` - it shows only `example`

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov: That data is not provided in your question and unfortunately you don't have all substitution rules stated so answer has to be based on data provided only.

Comment: I wrote about standard version suffixes. It is to last numbers with dash before them

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov it might be better to add rules/examples for standard version suffixes to  question.. I constructed the command in my answer based on examples alone.. which is what has likely happened here too

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. But this solution truncates filename after first 'dash digit point' sequence which surely isn't right: libexample-6.something.anything -> example